# Change the table row color based on Checkbox Selection? (I have two tables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tables.

In First table First column content is checkboxes.

If i select the checkbox in First table-->First column Means Current row color changes for both tables,but i have a code for First table color change only.

How to do it for second table also,

My code:

```
 $('table input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {

    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

Tried Code For second table:

```
$(this).parents("table").next().find("tr:nth-child(1)")[1].css({ 'background-color': 'orange' })           
//but it does not works
```

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please? And a jsFiddle.net example too would help.

Comment: Andy that is my code ... second code i tried but it does not works. That tried code selects two rows,don't know y it selects two rows

Comment: seems to work already? http://jsfiddle.net/c8Q3S/

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your jquery so that it is not applied to every table.

For example

```
$('table.colorchange input[type=checkbox]'). ...
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/c8Q3S/1/